# What does ./gradlew clean actually do?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I ran ./gradlew clean because my flutter run assembleDebug process was taking an unexpectedly long time. I expected it to delete my folder but instead it started downloading gradle.

`Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip`

Why was it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clean` task just deletes the build directory thus removing any previous builds, leftover files, etc. Therefore the next time you do a build, you will be starting from a clean state.

As for why it's downloading Gradle, that's because the Gradle Wrapper `./gradlew` could not find the particular version of Gradle on your machine, hence the download.